# General Journal AIF Services can't import offsets account of type customers - AX 2012

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I am trying to import data from a CSV file to AX 2012, using AIF, and consuming the Web Service through C# Web Application.

The data that I am trying to extract is from:

[image]

The web service I am using is the [basic GeneralJournalService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967432%28v=ax.50%29.aspx). The code used in the Web application to consume the Web Services is (assume it is Parsing CSV file for `string[]` and `ImportingHelper.EnumUtils.Parse` is parsing to an enum type):

```
public class ImportingJournals : ImportClass
{

           internal static int TransDateIndex = 0;
           internal static int AccountTypeIndex = 2;
           internal static int LedgerDimensionMainAccountIndex = 3;
           internal static int LedgerDimensionOnDisplayValueIndex = 4;
           internal static int LedgerDimensionValuesIndex = 5;
           internal static int DescriptionOnLineIndex = 6;
           internal static int DebittIndex = 7;   
           internal static int CreditIndex = 8;
           internal static int CurrencyIndex = 9;
           internal static int OffsetAccountTypeIndex = 10;
           internal static int OffsetMainAccountIndex = 11;  
           internal static int OffsetDisplayAccountIndex = 12;
           internal static int OffsetAccountValuesIndex = 13;
           internal static int JournalNameIndex = 14;
           internal static int DescriptionHeaderIndex = 15;
           internal static int CompanyIndex = 16;
           internal static int OffsetCompanyIndex = 16;
           internal static int FromCompanyIndex = 16;

           internal static int  ActiveIndex = 3;
           internal static int  ApproveIndex = 4;
           internal static int  FixedOffsetAccountIndex = 5;


           internal static int  ApprovalWorkflowIndex = 8;
           internal static int DetailLevelIndex = 12;
           internal static int FeesPostingIndex = 13;
           internal static int LinesLimitIndex = 14;
           internal static int PrivateForUserGroupIndex = 15;
           internal static int VoucherSeriesIndex = 16;
           internal static int NewVoucherIndex = 17;
           internal static int NumberAllocationAtPostingIndex = 18;
           internal static int DocumentIndex = 19; 
           internal static int FixedRateIndex = 20;

           internal static int AmountIncludedSalesTaxIndex = 22;
           internal static int HideSalesTaxFieldsInJournalEntryFormIndex = 23;


           internal static int LanguageIndex = 27;


           internal static int DescriptionTransIndex = 30;




        public void CreateFromCSVFile()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CreateFromCSVFile(System.IO.Stream fileStream)
        {

            GeneralJournalServiceClient generalJournalServiceClient = new GeneralJournalServiceClient();




            try
            {
                List<string[]> JournalData = Helper.ImportCSVFile.ParseCSVFile(fileStream, true);

                foreach (string[] journal in JournalData)
                {
                    CallContext callContext = new CallContext();

                    callContext.Company = journal[CompanyIndex];
                    callContext.Language = "en-gb";

                    AxdLedgerGeneralJournal journalEntity = new AxdLedgerGeneralJournal();

                    AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable journalHeader = new LedgerServices.AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable();


                    journalHeader.JournalName = journal[JournalNameIndex].Trim();
                    journalHeader.Name = journal[DescriptionHeaderIndex].Trim();

                    if (journal[DetailLevelIndex] != String.Empty)
                    {
                        journalHeader.DetailSummaryPostingSpecified = true;
                        AxdEnum_DetailSummary? parsingDetailSummary = ImportingHelper.EnumUtils.Parse<AxdEnum_DetailSummary>("Detail");
                        if (parsingDetailSummary != null)
                            journalHeader.DetailSummaryPosting = (AxdEnum_DetailSummary) parsingDetailSummary;

                    }
                    else
                        journalHeader.DetailSummaryPostingSpecified = false;

                    journalHeader.DetailSummaryPosting = AxdEnum_DetailSummary.Detail;

                    AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans journalLine = new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans();

                    if (journal[TransDateIndex] != null)
                    {
                        journalLine.TransDateSpecified = true;
                        journalLine.TransDate = DateTime.Parse(journal[TransDateIndex]);
                    }
                    else
                        journalLine.TransDateSpecified = false;

                    if (journal[AccountTypeIndex] != null)
                    {
                        journalLine.AccountTypeSpecified = true;

                        AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType? parsingLedgerJournalACType = ImportingHelper.EnumUtils.Parse<AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType>(journal[AccountTypeIndex]);
                        if (parsingLedgerJournalACType != null)
                            journalLine.AccountType = (AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType)parsingLedgerJournalACType;
                    }
                    else
                        journalLine.AccountTypeSpecified = false;

                    AxdType_MultiTypeAccount LedgerDimension = new AxdType_MultiTypeAccount();


                    LedgerDimension.DisplayValue = journal[LedgerDimensionOnDisplayValueIndex];
                    LedgerDimension.Account = journal[LedgerDimensionMainAccountIndex];
                    journalLine.LedgerDimension = LedgerDimension;

                    journalLine.Txt = journal[DescriptionOnLineIndex];

                    if (journal[DebittIndex] != String.Empty)
                    {
                        journalLine.AmountCurDebitSpecified = true;
                        journalLine.AmountCurDebit = Decimal.Parse(journal[DebittIndex]);
                    }
                    else
                        journalLine.AmountCurDebitSpecified = false;

                    if (journal[CreditIndex] != String.Empty)
                    {
                        journalLine.AmountCurCreditSpecified = true;
                        journalLine.AmountCurCredit = Decimal.Parse(journal[CreditIndex]);
                    }
                    else
                        journalLine.AmountCurCreditSpecified = false;

                    if (journal[OffsetAccountTypeIndex] != String.Empty)
                    {
                        journalLine.OffsetAccountTypeSpecified = true;
                        AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType? parsingLedgerJournalACType = ImportingHelper.EnumUtils.Parse<AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType>(journal[OffsetAccountTypeIndex]);
                        if (parsingLedgerJournalACType != null)
                            journalLine.OffsetAccountType = (AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType)parsingLedgerJournalACType;

                    }
                    else
                        journalLine.OffsetAccountTypeSpecified = false;

                    AxdType_MultiTypeAccount ledgerOffsetDimension = new AxdType_MultiTypeAccount();
                    ledgerOffsetDimension.Account = journal[OffsetMainAccountIndex];
                    ledgerOffsetDimension.DisplayValue = journal[OffsetDisplayAccountIndex];
                    journalLine.OffsetLedgerDimension = ledgerOffsetDimension;

                    journalLine.CurrencyCode = journal[CurrencyIndex];


                    journalLine.OffsetCompany = journal[OffsetCompanyIndex];


                    journalLine.Company = journal[FromCompanyIndex];


                    AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans[]  journalTransCollection =  new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans[1] 
                    {
                        journalLine
                    };

                    journalHeader.LedgerJournalTrans = journalTransCollection;
                    journalEntity.LedgerJournalTable = 
                    new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable[1] 
                    {
                        journalHeader
                    };

     generalJournalServiceClient.create(callContext, journalEntity);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String message = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                generalJournalServiceClient.Close();
            }
```

If somebody knows  how to solve this problem, please let me know. Transactions between Banks and Ledgers are possible. But transactions between Bank and Customer are not possible. I am getting the error:

**The offset account type must be one of the following types: Ledger, Bank.**

I don't know if the problem is if the General Journal Service recognizes the OffsetAccount Cust.

Answer (score 1):

After hours digging what could it be, I tough could be some configuration data, but the problem is very similar to one reported in this blog:

http://www.amer-ax.com/2011/06/how-to-use-the-gl-aif-service-to-integrate-non-ledger-transactions/

The web service provides the classes on C#:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes")]
    public enum AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType {

        /// <remarks/>
        Ledger,

        /// <remarks/>
        Cust,

        /// <remarks/>
        Vend,

        /// <remarks/>
        Project,

        /// <remarks/>
        FixedAssets,

        /// <remarks/>
        Bank,
    }
```

and

```
 /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=9)]
        public System.Nullable<AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType> OffsetAccountType {
            get {
                return this.offsetAccountTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.offsetAccountTypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("OffsetAccountType");
            }
        }
```

But AX 2012 doesn't support it at the other side in X++. Looking at the method `validateOffsetAccountType` of the `LedgerTransType`  class:

```
protected boolean validateOffsetAccountType()
{
    boolean isValid = true;

    switch (ledgerJournalTable.JournalType)
    {
        case LedgerJournalType::Daily :
                if (ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetAccountType != LedgerJournalACType::Ledger &&
                    ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetAccountType != LedgerJournalACType::Bank)
                {
                    if (this.isConsumerStateTracked())
                    {
                        // service limitation
                        isValid = AifFault::checkFailedLogFault("@SYS118081", #OffsetAccountTypeIsNotSupported);
                    }
                }
            break;

        default :
            break;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: As you mention, modification is needed in validateOffsetAccountType to support customer journals(or you should use a different service)